# USB-C and NFC U2F Keys

Tags: u2f

Are there any commercially available U2F keys that support both USB-C and NFC?

So far I've looked at [Yubico](https://www.yubico.com/store/) which seems to have a USB-C model that doesn't have NFC support or a USB-A model that does support NFC.

I've also found the [solokeys](https://solokeys.com/preorder/) site which seems to be what I'm looking for but not available yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type, "what products/services do X?" are off-topic as the answers could be a never ending list.

Comment: It falls under the open ended category as I mentioned

Comment: And as the market grows, the answers will grow

Comment: I just googled your question and got hits...

Comment: Yes, I believe closing questions of this type makes this Q&A site better. There has to be the possibility of a single acceptable answer.

Comment: While sitting here I found 3 options. Also, I would suggest using a USB adapter to convert the options that do not have the correct connector. I do.